# Issue with locating element from a drop-down using Selenium WebDriver (java)

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, xpath

I'm building a test automation pack using Selenium Webdriver, coding in Java with Eclipse. I have an issue which is probably best highlighted with the attachment here…… https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MoXi.jpg

I am basically trying to select the ‘Eclipse Deal Target’ option from the drop-down list. The code I am using to do this is as below:

```
    public static void eclipseDealTargetsFocus(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnEclipseDealTargets(driver);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/div/ul/li[4]/ul/li[5]/ul/li[2]/a")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

I’ve tried various ways of locating the element, using xpath locators but I keep getting an exception advising the element cannot be found. I even tried putting a fluent wait command in, incase the element took a while to become visible, but this did not rectify it. It’s all the more strange, as I am able to select any of the other options from the drop down list, e.g. CCL report, Eclipse Summary etc.

If anyone has had any experience of this and is able to help, that would be great. Furthermore, if I need to provide any more information please let me know.

Comment: From looking at the image, it appears that you have 'pop out' lists? As in they appear when a previous element is clicked or mouse-over'd?

Comment: Hi Mark, yes that's correct, they're pop-out lists.

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to use the 'Actions()' class that will allow you to 'fake' the mouse input that would reveal each list in turn.

Comment: Thanks very much Mark, that's resolved my issue. Could you mark that down in the answer section, so I can put an up-score against your answer, please?